# Why when I use a mutex variable it didn't lock the code correctly? anytime the function return me a different answers

Tags: c, multithreading

All the includes and the global varaibles:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

pthread_mutex_t sum_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
long sum = 0;
long primeCounter = 0;
```

I would like to know why the mutex didn't lock this two variables and every time after compiling this code and run it I got a different answers it is make me crazy I tried to change the block of the mutex to other places but still it don't work. Here is the main code which do the problem :

```
    void *main_routine(void *context){
    int processorsNumber = 10;
    struct readThreadParams *param = context;
    //init rundom generator

    int random;
    srand(param->randomPivot);
    //generate random numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < param->numOfRandomNumbers / processorsNumber; i++){
        random = rand();
        if (isPrime(random)){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&sum_lock);
            sum = sum + random;  // this is one of the variable.
            primeCounter++; // this is the second varaible
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&sum_lock);
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

This is the main which call to the threds:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc != 3){
        printf("Too few arguments ");
        printf("USAGE: ./primeCalc <prime pivot> <num of random numbers>");
        exit(0);
    }

    int i = 0;
    struct readThreadParams readParams;
    readParams.randomPivot = atoi(argv[1]);
    readParams.numOfRandomNumbers = atoi(argv[2]);
    int processorsNumber = 10;
    pthread_t *th = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * processorsNumber);

    for (i = 0; i < processorsNumber; i++){
        if (pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, &main_routine, &readParams) != 0){  
        return 1;
      }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < processorsNumber; i++){
        if (pthread_join(th[i], NULL) != 0){
            return 1;
       }
    }


    pthread_mutex_destroy(&sum_lock);
    //keep the out format as this!!
    printf("%ld,%ld\n", sum, primeCounter);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: What answer do you expect? What answers did your program produce?

Comment: If possible, please provide a [mre].

Comment: Please don't post double-spaced.

Comment: Sorry about all the mistakes it is my first post about the two spaces I didn't know what to do. about the expecting answers input :  6->seed, 10000000 -> check limit the output should be , to the sum of all the prime numbers is 513297223889453, and the counter of prime numbers is 490503

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [`rand()` is not guaranteed to be thread-safe](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html): "The rand function is not required to avoid data races with other calls to pseudo-random sequence generation functions. ..."

Second, `srand(param->randomPivot);` in every thread is going to destroy your program's ability to produce the same results given the same seed.

When any one thread calls `srand()` you have no idea when that happens in relation to every other thread calling both `srand()` to seed the random number generator or calling `rand()` to obtain a random number.

You need to call `srand()` ***once***, probably in the main thread **before** starting any other threads that call `rand()`.

Comment: Andrew i called the srand in the main and its fixed ty so much !!!!

Answer (score 1):

The `rand` and `srand` function use internal state and is therefore not reentrant.  This means that each of your threads interfere with each other when they call `srand` and `rand`.

You want to instead use `rand_r` which takes a state parameter.  This way each thread can maintain its own rng state.

```
void *main_routine(void *context){
    int processorsNumber = 10;
    struct readThreadParams *param = context;
    //init rundom generator

    unsigned int state = param->randomPivot;
    int random;
    //generate random numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < param->numOfRandomNumbers / processorsNumber; i++){
        random = rand_r(&state);
        if (isPrime(random)){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&sum_lock);
            sum = sum + random;  // this is one of the variable.
            primeCounter++; // this is the second varaible
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&sum_lock);
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Hey dbush thank you for helping, now the answer is not changing, but it is not the good answer the expected answer that I need to get when the input is 6 1000000 the output 
 should be this 51334773872090,49014. but I get this one 51176523249444,47748. if prime function work well...

Comment: Try running with a smaller upper limit to better debug.  Also, do you realize that each thread is processing the same set of numbers?